# Find the closest previous mark in a Tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a text widget, with three lines of text. I want to know which region of text the "insert" cursor is currently in. I have set marks using the `mark_set()` method and tried obtaining the closest previous mark using the `mark_previous()` method but the previous mark in the list is always "tk::anchor1". Is there a way of getting the closest previous *user-defined* mark to the cursor?

Here is an illustrative example. When I hit the button I want it to print out region 1, 2, or 3 depending on the position of the cursor.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.text = tk.Text()
        self.text.pack()
        self.strings = ["Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3"]
        for text in self.strings:
            self.text.mark_set(text, "insert")
            self.text.mark_gravity(text, "left")
            self.text.insert("insert", "{}\n".format(text))
        for mark in self.strings:
            print(self.text.index(mark))
        self.button = tk.Button(text="Find Region", command=self.find_region)
        self.button.pack()

    def find_region(self):
        region = self.text.mark_previous("insert")
        print("You are in region {}".format(region))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

Updated - The second `for` loops print out the mark indices as expected (1.0, 2.0, 3.0) but the mark_previous is not finding them.

Comment: If you want to detect entire regions, you might have better luck by setting a tag on the region, rather than setting a mark at one end of the region.

Comment: Are you aware that the way you wrote your code, all four marks have an index of 4.0? No matter where you are, the previous mark will never be one of your custom marks.

Comment: In the code you posted, is it your intention that the mark "Region 1" be at the _start_ of the first line, or at the _end_ of the first line?

Comment: You're right Bryan, all of the marks have an index of 4.0. My intention was to have the mark at the start of each line ("1.0", "2.0", "3.0") I realise the "insert" and "mark_set" commands are the wrong way around on the example I posted above, that was a mistake, but swapping the order doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The problem was that I needed to set the gravity to "left" - this fixes the mark indices but "mark_previous" command still returns "tk::anchor1". mark_names returns the list of ('insert', 'current', 'Region 1', 'Region 2', 'Region 3')

Answer (score 0):

For some reason using the "index" mark directly doesn't seem to work. But if I change the line to

```
region = self.text.mark_previous(self.text.index("insert"))
```

It works fine and as expected.